# Как вывести текст-ссылку в python3

Tags: python-3.x

Мне нужно вывести текст в консоль и чтобы по нажатию на этот текст в браузере открывалась страничка

например выведем:
текст

и чтобы по нажатию нас отправляло на сайт

Comment: Не бывает. В виндовой консоли такого функционала нет точно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто печатайте полную ссылку:

```
print("http://example.com")
```

и если терминал поддерживает, то вы сможете открыть ссылку, зависящим от конкретного терминала способом.

Например, в GNOME terminal на Ubuntu если навести мышь на ссылку, то она выделяется подчеркиванием и <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> позволяет открыть её или используя  [<kbd>⌘ + double-click</kbd> на OS X в Terminal.app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2339538/4279).

[`webbrowser` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html) позволяет сразу ссылку открыть:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("http://example.com")
```